# Undefined Reference error C

Tags: c++, avro

i am new to C programming (coming from Python) and want to do some performance tests with python. However i can not compile my code. I use CLion for programming with the standard toolchain (cmake and GDB7.8). This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(tests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(tests ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

My Code:

```
#include <avro.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    avro_file_reader_t dbreader;
    avro_file_reader("foo",&dbreader);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){

    }
}
```

I installed avro from the provided files and followed the given instruction and i additionally put the src file into my include folder.

This is the error:
/

```
home/marius/Programme/clion-1.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/marius/.clion11/system/cmake/generated/875d9c6/875d9c6/Debug --target all -- -j 8
Scanning dependencies of target tests
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tests.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable tests
CMakeFiles/tests.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion `main':
/home/marius/ClionProjects/tests/main.cpp:25: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `avro_file_reader'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tests] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tests.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

The German error message means "undefined reference".

Comment: *"I installed avro from the provided files and followed the given instruction and i additionally put the src file into my include folder."* Is `avro.h` part of the compiler library? If it's local to your project you could try `#include "avro.h"` note the different syntax.

Comment: My comment was ticked up but I now see the messages are from the linker. BTW isn't this a C++ question?

Comment: You need to tell CMake to add `-lavro` or something similar to the compilation (linking).  You may need to specify the directory where it is found.  If the header is in `/usr/avro/include`, there's a fair chance the library is `/usr/avro/lib`, for any install directory such as `/usr/avro`.  Your question doesn't show where the `avro.h` header is found, unfortunately.  (I don't like compilation systems that don't tell me what they're doing, precisely because when something goes wrong, it is hard to work out what they're doing and therefore fix it.)

Comment: In complement of Jonathan Leffler: use target_link_libraries(tests -lavro)

Comment: Your title and question refer to C, but the question is tagged "c++" and your source file is named `main.cpp`. C and C++ are two different languages. Which one are you using?